# Can a user see all the files in my website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I'm pretty new to web development. I'm creating a website using Node.js and express. I need to store some very private information in these files (codes dealing with payments, etc.) but also just some stuff in the server side that the client can't alter/see. I have searched the internet and have had no luck, so what files can the users access when they use my website? (This is how I have everything organized)...

[image]

How can I make sure that this private information is not exposed. All help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Everything you have in your screenshot looks like a frontend app. Most things in the frontend or client side cannot be secured. Secrets need to be on a server side, which can be an aws lambda among other things if you like.

Comment: If you set up your server appropriately, then nothing will be sent to the browser that you don't want to be sent there.  You can control that.  Secrets that should remain on the server can be protected and never sent to the client.  You do have to set up your server correctly to make sure this is the case.

Comment: @DCTID - That's not all front-end stuff.   `app.js` is probably nodejs code.  `views` are server-side templates.  `routes` are express route definitions.

Answer (score 1):

### Runtime Environment

First, you runtime environment is Node.js so your logic is store in server-side, anything else such as javascript, images, css, html consider as static resources you watch them inside your browser by going to **Resources/Source tab** in Developer Tools (depends which browser you are using).

[image]

### JavaScript

Browser did solve math then send response to console always!

Client-side runs via browser in a client machine. E.g.

```
var mathInBrowser = (1 + 1);
    
console.log("mathInBrowser")
```

### NodeJS

Server solves math then send response/value to specific route only when requested. So the browser doesn't know if this equation, it knows only the value. Because Node.js is server-side runtime environment, it runs JavaScript Files and more inside a server and send only what needed to be sent to the browser or API. E.g.

```
var mathInServer = 1 + 1;

app.get('/math', function(req, res) {

res.send("Result is: " + mathInServer)
})
```

### Database

You can send data from your requests to databases that has no access except via authentication process. In that way you are storing valuable information in place that only authorized personnel can access.

### Important

Don't store important information in public folder thinking that no one would recognize! As public resources anyone can see your files and your codes if you upload it as static assets. Sometimes, search engines can explode serious client informations, links, files.

Comment: thank you so much! just as clarification, when using node.js server side my server information is secure correct?

Comment: As for server information if you type in terminal `curl -I http://localhost:APP-PORT` You can request `HEAD` response should be server information e.g. `X-Powered-By` your situation should be `Express`, and more useful information such as `content-type` of requested resources, HTTP protocol supported..etc. Therefore, I suggest  to start using `Nginx` to secure your apps. In that way, you can hide your app ports and more. You must adopt `https` via Node.js library or at least via `Nginx` reserve proxy that supports SSL. Think of security as layers lev.0, lev.1, lev.2 ..etc as you adopting.